# TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined - Bootstrap 4 Carousel - Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have been trying to add a carousel to the top of the news section of a Rails 5 app. I am using rails 5, bootstrap 4 and haml. The carousel I have is

```html
#carousel-example-generic.carousel.slide{"data-ride" => "carousel"}
  %ol.carousel-indicators
    %li.active{"data-slide-to" => "0", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
    %li{"data-slide-to" => "1", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
    %li{"data-slide-to" => "2", "data-target" => "#carousel-example-generic"}
  .carousel-inner{:role => "listbox"}
    .carousel-item.active
      %img{:alt => "First slide", "src" => "#{@news.image.url(:medium)}"}/
    .carousel-item
      %img{:alt => "Second slide", "src" => "#{@news.image.url(:medium)}"}/
    .carousel-item
      %img{:alt => "Third slide", "src" => "#{@news.image.url(:medium)}"}/
  %a.left.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#carousel-example-generic", :role => "button"}
    %span.icon-prev{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
    %span.sr-only Previous
  %a.right.carousel-control{"data-slide" => "next", :href => "#carousel-example-generic", :role => "button"}
    %span.icon-next{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
    %span.sr-only Next
```

I am getting the error; 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined.

I have seen other examples of this question but their solution was that they hadn't added active classes but i have them on both the item and the list item. Dont know if anyone else can see my mistake or encountered this issue?

Comment: This didn't display the error you posted when tested in Rails 5 with Bootstrap 4. Add additional information if possible.

Comment: So you managed to get it working on rails 5?

Comment: I tested it with: *Rails 5.0.0.beta3*, *ruby 2.3.1p112* with *gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'* Here are some [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/NXQ01).

Comment: Well, that certainly seems to be working... and i assume you can move left and right because that is when the error is being triggered... if not ill have another look at code the carousel is interacting with. Thanks for helping me with this

Comment: It works as expected with no errors when triggering the slides, granted there is nothing else going on in this App outside of the Carousel since it was just to test it for errors and nothing more.